# How to properly make a container view that contains some viewControllers(programmatically)?

Tags: ios, swift

I want to create a container View programmatically that has inside a bunch of view controllers. I have a segmented controller that when the user tapped a button it should display a certain viewController without doing a segue.
I have everything inside a ViewController,
I wanted to know how to properly make the segmented controller display a certain view controller when tapped.

```
func setUpSegmentedControl() {
    let seg = UISegmentedControl(items: ["1", "2", "3"])
    seg.selectedSegmentIndex = 0
    seg.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    seg.layer.cornerRadius = 8  
    seg.backgroundColor = UIColor.white 
    seg.addTarget(self, action: #selector(changeColor(sender:)), for: .valueChanged)
   view.addSubview(seg)

           NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
 seg.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerXAnchor),                                                     seg.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.centerYAnchor),                                     seg.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),                                   seg.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor),                                seg.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50)

        ])
}   

 @objc func changeColor(sender: UISegmentedControl) {
    switch sender.selectedSegmentIndex {
    case 0:
        addChild(FirstViewController())

        print("1")
    case 1:
        addChild(SecondViewController())

    print("2")
    default:
        addChild(ThirdViewController())

        print("3")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To add a view controller to a container view programmatically, you need to call `addSubview` and `didMove` in addition to `addChild`.

```
let firstViewController = FirstViewController()
addChild(firstViewController)
firstViewController.view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
containerView.addSubview(firstViewController.view) // replace `containerView` with the name of the view that's supposed to contain the VC's view

// add constraints or set frame manually
let trailingConstraint = firstViewController.view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor)
let leadingConstraint = firstViewController.view.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor)
let topConstraint = firstViewController.view.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor)
let bottomConstraint = firstViewController.view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor)
NSLayoutConstraint.activate([trailingConstraint, leadingConstraint, topConstraint, bottomConstraint])

firstViewController.didMove(to parent: self)
```

If you want to remove a child view controller programatically:

```
let child = children.first // or other way to identify your VC
child?.willMove(toParentViewController: nil)
child?.view.removeFromSuperview()
child?.view.removeFromParentViewController()
```

[Example project](https://github.com/nambatee/SegmentedViewControllers)

Comment: it works but when it starts at the first, the first button is tapped by default and it doesn't display the firstViewController, until I tap the second button and then go back to the first button then it does display the firstViewController

Comment: @Jose That's because you don't call `changeColor` until you tap a button. Try calling `changeColor` after `setUpSegmentedControl`. Remember to remove your child VC before you add it again.

Comment: now it shows the firstViewController at first by default but when it shows the first time puts space on the firstViewController and the Segmented controller, can you help me?

Comment: @Jose I updated my answer with a link to a sample project that does what you're trying to do.